# How did sed 's/.*\[//g;s/].*//g;s/:.*//g' work here

Tags: bash, unix, sed

a question regarding sed.

Using this command
`sed 's/.*\[//g;s/].*//g;s/:.*//g'`

With this input

```
172.19.0.100 - - [16/Feb/2020:22:31:32 +0000] "GET /site HTTP/1.1" 200 36565 "https://command-not-found.com/curl" "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)" "172.19.0.3"
172.19.0.101 - - [16/Feb/2020:22:30:10 +0000] "GET /credits HTTP/1.1" 200 31067 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)" "172.19.0.2"
172.19.0.102 - - [17/Feb/2020:22:30:10 +0000] "GET /index HTTP/1.1" 200 31067 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)" "172.19.0.2"
172.19.0.100 - - [18/Feb/2020:22:35:10 +0000] "GET /index HTTP/1.1" 200 31067 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)" "172.19.0.2"
```

Can anyone walk me thru what does the sed do step by step? I'm trying to be more adept with it and this is a bit overwhelming for me

Expected Result

```
1 18/Feb/2020
1 17/Feb/2020
1 15/Feb/2020
```

I tried playing around with it on https://sed.js.org/ but it keeps on saying file cannot be read.

The whole code I'm trying to read and understand is this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
LOG_FILE="$1"

function request_per_day() {
    declare -A day_array
    while read line; do
        day=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/.*\[//g;s/].*//g;s/:.*//g')
        if [[ -v day_array[$day] ]]; then
            day_array[$day]=$((day_array[$day]+1))
        else
            day_array[$day]=1
        fi
    done < $LOG_FILE

    for day in ${!day_array[@]}; do echo ${day_array[$day]} $day; done | sort -rn | head -10
}

function request_per_ip() {
    declare -A ip_array
    while read line; do
        ip=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
        if [[ -v ip_array[$ip] ]]; then
            ip_array[$ip]=$((ip_array[$ip]+1))
        else
            ip_array[$ip]=1
        fi
    done < $LOG_FILE

    for ip in ${!ip_array[@]}; do echo ${ip_array[$ip]} $ip; done | sort -rn | head -10
}

request_per_day
echo ""
request_per_ip
```

Although I understand most of it, I don't really get how did the sed and awk worked in this example.

And lastly, what does this `if [[ -v day_array[$day] ]]` test for exactly?

Comment: Trying to learn something like `sed` by dropping examples in SO and asking for a step-by-step explanation is terribly inefficient. If you cannot understand the rather simple `sed` script you show, the best to do is probably to read the manual. `man sed`, `man awk`, `man bash` are your best friends. Try the usually more complete `info` instead of `man`  if you do not find what you searched for.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: try the cool sed debugger [sedsed](https://github.com/aureliojargas/sedsed).

Answer (score 0):

After posting this question, I managed to stumble upon a resource that basically answers how stringing together sed commands and wildcards. Managed to figure it out.

Here's what they do and their results.

```
s/.*[//g
```

Searches for all the pattern before `[` and replaces them with nothing (deletes them) and the result would be:

```
15/Feb/2020:22:32:02 +0000] "GET /index HTTP/1.1" 200 14034 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/6~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)" "172.19.0.4"
```

The next sed command would be

```
s/].*/g
```

Now this searches for anything after the `]` and replaces them with nothing (deleting them) which yields a result of:

```
15/Feb/2020:22:32:02 +0000
```

And lastly

```
s/:.*//g
```

This searches for anything after `:` and replaces them with nothing resulting in

`15/Feb/2020`